# Prove that if $\alpha + \beta$ equals $\omega^{\gamma}$, then $\beta$ equals either $0$ or $\omega^{\gamma}.$

Tags: set-theory, exponentiation, ordinals

I'm trying to show whenever $β<ω^γ$, $β$  has to be zero. The plan is that if  $γ_0=γ$  is a limit ordinal, then $ω^{γ_0}$ being **sup**$\{ω^ε|ε<γ_0\}$, $β<ω^{γ_0}$ entails there exists $γ_1<γ_0$ such that $β<ω^{γ_1}$. If $γ_1$ is again a limit, then we can similarly find $γ_2<γ_1$ such that $β<ω^{γ_2}$, etc. If we never run into any non-limit $γ_i$, this process constructs a strictly decreasing sequence of ordinals, $γ_0>γ_1>γ_2>\cdots$, which must terminate at zero. Since $β<ω^{γ_i}$ for all $i$, we have $β<ω^0=1$ as expected.

To complete the proof, however, still we should address what if we do encounter $β<ω^{γ_i}$ where $γ_i$ is not a limit, say, $γ_i=ε+1$. If $β<ω^ε$, it's fine. If $β\geqω^ε$, I was able to convince myself that $β+ω^{γ_i}=ω^{γ_i}$. This is because (i) $β+ω^{γ_i}\geqω^ε+ω^{γ_i}=ω^{γ_i}$; (ii) dividing $β$ by $ω^ε$ as $β=ω^εx+y$, where $x<ω$, $y<ω^ε$, it follows $β<ω^εx+ω^ε$, so $β+ω^{γ_i}\leqω^εx+ω^ε+ω^{γ_i}=ω^εx+ω^{γ_i}=ω^ε(x+ω)=ω^εω=ω^{γ_i}$ (*addition is non-decreasing in the first operand*).

Now I'm stuck at this point. I'll appreciate if someone can explain how to proceed on, or maybe the proof plan is wrong from the beginning...

**Update**

Yes, I realized the plan wasn't on the right track. The statement boils down to two claims,  (i) neither of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ exceed $ω^γ$, but (ii) they can't be both smaller than $ω^γ$ (as **Deedlit** mentions). (ii) follows from a simple fact that $β+ω^γ=ω^γ$ whenever $β<ω^γ$.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hint: If $\alpha,\beta < \omega^\gamma$, then $\alpha + \beta < \omega^\gamma$.

Comment: I see what you mean! It helps :) @Deedlit

Comment: You should aim to prove something stronger: If $\omega^\gamma $ is split into two sets, at least one of them has order-type $\omega^\gamma $.

Comment: @Deedlit Where can I find the proof for that? :(

Comment: First, show that if $\alpha < \omega^\gamma$, then $\alpha < \omega^\delta m$ for some $\delta < \gamma$ and finite ordinal $m$.  (If $\gamma$ is a successor ordinal, then we can let $\delta$ be the predecessor of $\gamma$; if $\gamma$ is a limit ordinal, then there is a successor ordinal $\epsilon < \gamma$ with $\alpha < \omega^\epsilon$.)  Then $\alpha + \beta < \omega^\delta m + \omega^\epsilon n \le \omega^{\max \{\delta,\epsilon\}}(m+n) < \omega^\gamma$ since $\delta,\epsilon < \gamma$.

Answer (score 1):

The case $\gamma = 0$ is trivial, so assume $\gamma > 0$.

If $\alpha + \beta = \omega^{\gamma}$ and $\beta \not \in \{0, \omega^{\gamma} \}$ then $\alpha < \omega^{\gamma} \wedge \beta < \omega^{\gamma}$. Hence
$$
\begin{align*}
\alpha + \beta &\overset{(\dagger)}{<} \alpha + \omega^\gamma \\
&\overset{(\ddagger)}= \sup \{ \alpha + \delta \mid \delta < \omega^\gamma \} \\
&\overset{\alpha < \omega^\gamma}{=} \sup \{ \delta \mid \delta < \omega^\gamma \} \\
&= \omega^\gamma
\end{align*}
$$
Contradiction!

$(\dagger)$ holds because ordinal addition is striclty increasing in the second coordinate.

$(\ddagger)$ holds because, for $\gamma \neq 0$, $\omega^\gamma$ is a limit ordinal.